# How to build a large C++ library with emscripten?

Tags: javascript, c++, webassembly, emscripten

I've followed the steps in [this](https://emscripten.org/docs/compiling/Building-Projects.html#integrating-with-a-build-system) example in order to compile a rather large C++ library to JavaScript.

The project has a `build.sh` in which I replaced **g++-7** with **emcc**.

I then ran `emcmake ./build.sh` which produced quite a lot of .o files

The last step in the example is to run `./emcc [-Ox] project.o -o project.js`.

I'm a bit unsure what to replace **project.o** with. Should I replace it with all the .o files produced by emcmake above or only the ones used when consuming the library in question?

Comment: Do you have a cmake config CMakeLists.txt in the project? Normally you should run ./emcmake cmake, but it depends what your script is supposed to do, and what do you expect to build (.bc files, static libs build with emscripten...). What does the build.sh? Can you post a part of it?

Comment: There's a CMakeList.txt. The build.sh script is for setting different vars like platform, configuration etc. It also seems to be using Ninja as a build system.

Comment: it depends on the build script, but can you build the static lib? or you can build a .bc (bitecode) file joining all the .o files and  build at the end the .js file as you written.

Comment: Yeah, replace project.o with all the *.o files that build.sh spit out. Are you building the library to be used from a javascript project or a C++ project? If C++ then output it to `project.a` (static lib) instead of a .js file. Also a bit of the `build.sh` would be helpful to know if you need to run it or just use the CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: In essence the `build.sh` script does `cmake --build ./build/cmdlinebuild --config release --target all -- -j 10` given the argument that I provide it with.

Comment: I'm building the library to be used from a JavaScript project.